# What is the meaning of "So away to the shool bus I flew"?

Tags: meaning, poetry

What is the meaning of "So away to the shool bus I flew" in the following sentence(Source: The Night Before The 100th DAY OF SCHOOL By Natasha Wing )

> The very next morning the big day was here.
>    Hooray for the 100th day of the school year!
>   **So away to the school bus I flew** in a flash,
>   Then hopped off the sidewalk and made a mad dash.

?

Does "So away to the school bus I flew in a flash" mean "Because I am so away from the school bus, I flew to the school bus in a flash" ?

Comment: Maybe it's *so... that ...* structure used? *So away to the school bus that I flew ...* I might be completely wrong. I'm not a native speaker. That's my best guess.

Comment: "Thus, I **flew away** to the school bus"

Comment: dan// I thank you for your answer. I only know how to read very simple English. There is a deep tolerance among people with similar circumstances. When I heard your answer, I too think so. Obsession is accompanied by nothingness, so I'm not so obsessed with learning English. Just because the world has changed and the information has been transmitted at the speed of light, 
I am trying to learn English to keep pace with a little bit in this rapidly changing world.

Comment: CowperKettle// If so, Do "So away to the school bus I flew in a flash" mean not "I flew to the school bus that is so away from me in a flash" but "I flew so away to the school bus in a flash" ?

Comment: @user22046 - **So** in this sentence just means "therefore", or "because of that", and it modifies the entire sentence, not just "away".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The meaning is

> I **flew away** to the school bus.

"Flew away" is the past simple form of **fly away**. To **fly away** is to quickly move **from** something: the word **away** here means **from**. Thus, the boy quickly moved, ran ("flew") **from** the point where he was initially (from his home, most likely). Thus,

> So, I quickly ran **from** (away) my home towards the bus.

With the word **away**, you don't need to indicate **from where** exactly you flew. Whatever the place you are at the moment, you can **fly away**.